# how to use dropwizard for already developed web application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jetty, dropwizard

We have two web applications, which are already developed using Servlets and Jsp'.

generally we build them using ant and deploy on jetty server.

we would like to make build and deploying process easy. so how we can use dropwizard for our purpose or is there any other frame work we can use to make deployment and launching web applications easy.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

in theory, nothing stops you from overwriting the ServerFactory and creating your own servlets there. You can then have that in DropWizard and things *should* work. (see DefaultServerFactory)

Problem with this is, that you are now using DW as a running container and you don't take any advantage of any features it offers you. So it really makes no sense to use that with your setup I think.

Alternatively, if you want to run and deploy into jetty, may I suggest you look into the maven jetty plugin? http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html 
It is not my favourite way of running it, but I have seen a lot of people using it. You essentially configure your application to use this plugin and add configuration on how to set up the connectors for jetty. Afterwards, all you need to do for running is "mvn jetty:run".